# String interpolation on the result of a function that returns string

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I have a function which gets some text from an xml file like this:

```
var text = Translate("/foo/bar");
```

Now in the XML I want to put in string interpolation constants like this:

```
<foo>
  <bar>Hi, {firstName} {lastName}!</bar>
</foo>
```

So, I want to do string interpolation on the result of the Translate-function, that would be something like:

```
var firstName = "John";
var lastName = "Smith";
var formattedText = $Translate("/foo/bar");
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
Is there any way to to this, except reverting to string.Format ?

It could be nice if the dollar sign could be placed in front of anything that is a string, be it a variable, a string or a function, to do string interpolation.

It's worth mentioning that I don't have control over the code for the Translate-function, since it's in a third party component.

Comment: There are a few utility classes written for this kind of thing (e.g., [FormatWith](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables)).  However, they tend to have undocumented idiosyncrasies.  This does sacrifice the protection of the type system, but that's an inherent downside of run-time string formatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't do this. String interpolation is performed at *compile-time*. The compiler examines the interpolated string literal, finds the relevant format strings and converts them to `{0}` etc. There's nothing similar to perform this at execution time.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that.

String interpolation is part compiler magic, you can't inject string interpolation back into a normal string. Since you can't change the `Translate` method, it will still return a string and thus you're left with having to do this yourself.

Since all the heavy lifting (finding the expressions, extracting them, rewriting the actual string, etc.) is done at compile time there is no runtime classes that can help you do this.

---

Now, if *all* you have is the name of things, and not *expressions* in the returned string, then you *could* do this yourself. In other words, the exact example you've shown shouldn't be *too* hard. However, it would still not be "string interpolation" as such, it would be your own thing. In other words, if the returned string ever contained something like `".... {firstname:-40} ..."` you're in for a tough ride.

The *simplest* naive solution would be to do simple string replacements:

```
var formattedText = $Translate("/foo/bar")
    .Replace("{firstname}", firstname)
    .Replace("{lastname}", lastname);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can transform your variables into an anonymous (or defined object), you could use SmartFormat (https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET).

```
var obj = new [MyClass - optional, if declared]
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Smith",
}

var formattedText = Smart.Format(Translate("/foo/bar"), obj);
```

The reason your code doesn't work, as I understand, is that interpolated strings are evaluated (variables in it), during compile time, not during runtime.